# Kann man eine gute Besserung wünschen?

Tags: grammaticality

What is the difference in meaning between "Ich wünsche Dir eine gute Besserung." and "Ich wünsche Dir gute Besserung."? Is the first example even correct?

Comment: "Ich wünsche Dir gute Besserung" is shorter. No, this isn't an exhaustive answer, which is why I don't post it as such.

Answer (score 5):

Both are correct and are used. "Ich wünsche Dir gute Besserung" is shorter.

One could probably try to interpret the slightly different grammar as  different meaning, but in real world usage there is no difference in meaning between the two variants at all.

Answer (score 2):

To me the "eine gute Besserung" sounds a bit strange. The word "eine" suggests (or at least connotes) that "Besserung" is a countable thing - which it isn't. For the same reason you might wish someone "einen guten Tag" (a good day) but "Guten Appetit" (good appetite, the usual formula for starting a meal).

An English analogy would be that we wish "*a* good day" but "have fun" (not "have a fun").

I suppose one of the reasons why "eine gute Besserung" is used at all is because "gute Besserung" is considered to be so formulaic that the wish itself becomes "somewhat countable".

Comment: The analogy with _have fun_ is misleading. _have a fun_ is utterly wrong in English, while _Ich wünsche dir einen guten Tag_ is not wrong in German.

Comment: The examples hold because *(wish (to)) have fun* is a participle that should be well comparable to the noun phrase *a good day*, regardless if it does not appear as such with *I wish you...*, *I wish you two have fun* making that difficult to work out once duals gone astray. Ich *wünsch dir viel Spaß* / *einen schönen Tag* still holds. This implies tacitly that *gute* on its own is arbitrarily read as obligatory determiner since we never hear: *? ich wünsche dir _ Besserung*.

Comment: I also heard "Ich wünsch' dir einen guten Appetit". It could origin from around Hessia. There you'll also hear "Sprich mal mit dem Dominik" instead of "Sprich mal mit Dominik".

Comment: @JonathanScholbach: "Tag" is something *countable* and this is what i said - you can use "a" (or any definite number, for that matter) if the noun is countable, otherwise not. "Have *a* good day." ("day" is countable) but NOT: "I wish you *a* luck." ("luck" is not countable)

Comment: Sorry, my comment was ambiguous. I meant to write "while _eine gute Besserung_ is not wrong in German". The whole idea of countable vs uncountable is misleading here: _It is a great pleasure_ is perfectly fine in English, although pleasure is not countable. Same with _eine gute Besserung_ in German. The reason why \*_have a fun_ is wrong in English is not based on fun not being countable.

Comment: @JonathanScholbach: Das Problem mit der Zählbarkeit ist, dass sich mit viel Bemühung meist doch eine Z. herstellen lässt, etwa 3 Patienten im Krankenhaus und bei zweien konstatiert man eine Besserung. Allerdings wird es im Kontext eines Wunsches schwierig und daher meist falsch sein. Wieso "pleasures" nicht zählbar sein sollen leuchtet mir aber nicht ein. "Ich wünsche e. g. Besserung und eine weniger gute" käme in Betracht, wenn ein Soldat Fronturlaub aufgrund einer Verletzung hat, und zugleich einen bösen Husten, und die Verletzung verschleppen möchte, um nicht an die Front zurück zu müssen.

Comment: @infinitezero: Beim guten Appetit kommt auch eine Interferenz in Betracht mit der Floskel "er hat einen guten Appetit" im Sinne von "er frisst wie ein Mähdrescher".

Comment: If "pleasure" is not a countable thing, then how comes "many pleasures" is a phrase? Some words can be countable and uncountable depending on context, as @userunknown showed with "Besserung" - which is countable when used in respect to several (ill) people, Similar with i.e. "Fetch me a milk." where in fact a "glass of ..." (countable item) is meant.